# ESB 4.8.0 clustering Login Failed in Worker instance

Tags: authentication, wso2, cluster-computing, wso2-esb

i followed these guidelines in this WSO2 documentation page: http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29918203

I configured the ELB, ESB Manager and 2 ESB worker in cluster. I had not error logged in the log files and, when i create a sample-passthrough proxy in the manager i see the xml files correctly deployed in the two worker instances too (looking at the file system repository folder).
The problem is that if on one hand i can login in the admin console of the manager ESB, every time i try to login in the worker 1 and 2 conoles i get the "Login Failed" message.
Looking in the woker log file i see:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:26:13,088]  INFO   {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super   [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:26:13,088+0100]  {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:26:19,108]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:26:19,107+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:26:29,082]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:26:29,082+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:10,669] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager} -  Using sql : null {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:10,670] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Authentication Failure {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:10,670]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2014-02-25 12:27:10,670+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:25,702]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:27:25,702+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:28,155]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:27:28,155+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:30,862]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:27:30,862+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:32,466]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:27:32,466+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:34,194]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:27:34,194+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-02-25 12:27:34,826]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-02-25 12:27:34,826+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
```

Where is the error? What am i missing?
With the 4.7.0 version i was able to login each of the three esb.
thanks

Comment: Well, we don't expect the user to log in to worker nodes. In ESB 4.8.0 (which is on Carbon 4.2.0), multiple profiles were introduced and it will activate only the required bundles for worker profile. I haven't tried to login to worker nodes, so I'm not sure about the error you are getting.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean activated the required bundles for manager profile (the one which i can access)? or the worker one?

Comment: I mean the worker profile will not activate UI components. The manager (with default profile) will activate all required bundles

Comment: Well, we don't expect to log in to management console of worker nodes. Since we don't expected to do "management" stuff in "worker" nodes. Worker nodes just simply serve for service requests and balances service load.